How to show collection info in prestige theme shopify below the products not above?
when I activate the collection info for the collection page in Shopify admin I found that is displayed  at the top of the page and I want it to be below the products (prestige theme Shopify)
I didn't find a way to try it even when I added a meta filed it was not shown on the collection page
